# Read entire file in Scala?

Tags: scala

What's a simple and canonical way to read an entire file into memory in Scala?  (Ideally, with control over character encoding.)

The best I can come up with is:

```
scala.io.Source.fromPath("file.txt").getLines.reduceLeft(_+_)
```

or am I supposed to use one of [Java's god-awful idioms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731365/reading-and-displaying-data-from-a-txt-file), the best of which (without using an external library) seems to be:

```
import java.util.Scanner
import java.io.File
new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next()
```

From reading mailing list discussions, it's not clear to me that `scala.io.Source` is even supposed to be the canonical I/O library.  I don't understand what its intended purpose is, exactly.

... I'd like something dead-simple and easy to remember.  For example, in these languages it's very hard to forget the idiom ...

```
Ruby    open("file.txt").read
Ruby    File.read("file.txt")
Python  open("file.txt").read()
```

Comment: Java isnt that bad if you know the right tools. import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("file.txt", "UTF-8")

Comment: This comment misses the point of language design. Any language which has available a simple library function for exactly the operation you want to perform is therefore as good as its function invocation syntax. 

Given an infinite and 100% memorised library, all programs would be implemented with a single function call.

A programming language is good when it needs fewer pre-fab components to already exist in order to achieve a specific result.

Comment: I'm afraid "Given an infinite and 100% memorised library" is not a premise for any rational argument! Programming languages are for humans, and ideally should contain just the abstractions needed to glue things together

Comment: The best modern solution is to use Li's [os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) [as he mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56310888/1125159).  os-lib hides the Java ugliness and provides [Ruby-like elegance](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/).

Answer (score 488, accepted):

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").mkString
```

By the way, "`scala.`" isn't really necessary, as it's always in scope anyway, and you can, of course, import io's contents, fully or partially, and avoid having to prepend "io." too.

The above leaves the file open, however. To avoid problems, you should close it like this:

```
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")
val lines = try source.mkString finally source.close()
```

Another problem with the code above is that it is horribly slow due to its implementation. For larger files one should use:

```
source.getLines mkString "\n"
```

Comment: Ah, definitely better then reduceLeft(_+_).

Comment: I'm too late to the party, but I'd hate for people not to know they can do "io.File("/etc/passwd").slurp" in trunk.

Comment: I'd hate for Scala 2.8 to have a method called "`slurp`", but it seems I'm stuck with it anyway.

Comment: I would have been negotiable on the name, but due to your "utter disgust" I will do my best to keep it the way it is.  Thank you for your characteristic thanklessness.

Comment: @extempore If you truly think I'm thankless, I'm truly sorry. I deeply appreciate your support of the Scala language and each and every time you have personally looked into an issue I brought up, suggested a solution to a problem I had, or explained something to me. I'll take the opportunity, then, to thank you for turning scala.io into something decent and worthy. I'll be more vocal in my thanks from now on, but I still hate the name, sorry.

Comment: "slurp" has been the name for reading an entire file at once in Perl for many years. Perl has a more visceral and informal naming tradition than the C family of languages, which some may find distasteful, but in this case I think it fits: it's an ugly word for an ugly practice. When you slurp(), you know you're doing something naughty because you just had to type that.

Comment: "make suggestions instead" - Source should detect the file's encoding (within reason) and read it correctly. Unicode's BOMs are standard, and there are other metrics that are good enough to guess an encoding given the first hundred bytes of a file. I shouldn't have to invent something clever to detect a file that happens to be UCS-2. Yes, this has happened to me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen such code, but I definitely can't find it right now on trunk.

Comment: (I wasn't actually using Scala at the time...)

Comment: File.read() would be a nicer name, and consistent with Ruby and Python besides.

Comment: @extempore: you can't stop people from being disgusted.  It's just the way it is.  It shouldn't bother you that some people don't like every choice you've made. That's just life, you can't please everybody :)

Comment: Scala 2.8 doesn't have a `fromPath` method. `fromFile` is still being used, and still accepts the file name in a string.

Comment: @Hosam Yeah, they reverted that at the very end. Fixed.

Comment: Note that simply calling fromFile.getLines will instantiate a
Source instance but not close it. This means that the Scala runtime 
may retain a lock on the the file in the file system, preventing it
from being opened for write, renamed, removed, etc. as long as the
Scala Source insance is holding the lock. 

The following will read the files and also close the file.

    def linesFrom(fileName:String) : List[String] = {
       val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName)
       val text = source.getLines
       source.close()
       text
    }

Comment: @djb This lock is a Windows problem, but I take your point. It would leak file descriptors at any rate, which can be a serious problem. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: By the way, bare `mkString` (no `getLines`) is fixed in 2.11.

Comment: @RexKerr You mean speed-wise? Cool! I've gotta take a look at it. Did they override it at the iterator level?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - This is what "they" did: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2929

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Would the mkString part be a more complete platform independent implementation with: source.getLines mkString System.lineSeparator?

Comment: @Ben I don't think so. Once you have read it as a `String`, you are working with an internal Java representation, and in this representation `\n` is a new line. If you output that again, the output method _probably_ understands new line correctly. Only if you are going to output it, and then output method requires system-dependent new lines, would it be useful to do that.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Good to know.  So unless one plans to spit it out somewhere else, like stdo or another file, then there is no consequence.  Thank you.

Comment: @Ben Yes. And even spitting it out, `\n` is probably the right thing.

Answer (score 64):

Just to expand on Daniel's solution, you can shorten things up tremendously by inserting the following import into any file which requires file manipulation:

```
import scala.io.Source._
```

With this, you can now do:

```
val lines = fromFile("file.txt").getLines
```

I would be wary of reading an entire file into a single `String`.  It's a very bad habit, one which will bite you sooner and harder than you think.  The `getLines` method returns a value of type `Iterator[String]`.  It's effectively a lazy cursor into the file, allowing you to examine just the data you need without risking memory glut.

Oh, and to answer your implied question about `Source`: yes, it is the canonical I/O library.  Most code ends up using `java.io` due to its lower-level interface and better compatibility with existing frameworks, but any code which has a choice should be using `Source`, particularly for simple file manipulation.

Comment: OK.  There's a story for my negative impression of Source: I once was in a different situation than now, where I had a very large file that wouldn't fit into memory.  Using Source caused the program to crash; it turned out it was trying to read the whole thing at once.

Comment: Source is not supposed to read the whole file into memory. If you use toList after getLines, or some other method which will produce a collection, then you get everything into memory. Now, Source is a *hack*, intended to get the job done, not a carefully thought-out library. It will be improved in Scala 2.8, but there's definitely opportunity for the Scala community to become active in defining a good I/O API.

Answer (score 42):

Java 8+

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

val path = Paths.get("file.txt")
new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Java 11+

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path}

val path = Path.of("file.txt")
Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

These offer control over character encoding, and no resources to clean up. It's also faster than other patterns (e.g. `getLines().mkString("\n")`) due to more efficient allocation patterns.

Comment: To simplify, you can use `Files.readString​(Path.of("file.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: This answer should be ranked higher, as it's the shortest answer of the ones that actually *close the file*.
Sure, it uses Java APIs only, but that's fine in this case. (no mutability is exposed)

Comment: @Ava, thank you for the suggestion. I've updated for the more recent Java versions.

Comment: This is the best answer :+1:

Answer (score 37):

```
// for file with utf-8 encoding
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt", "utf-8").getLines.mkString
```

Comment: Adding "getLines" to the original answer will remove all newlines. Should be "Source.fromFile("file.txt", "utf-8").mkString".

Comment: See also my comment in the Daniel C. Sobral's answer - this use will not close the Source instance, so Scala may retain a lock on the file.

Answer (score 25):

(EDIT: This does not work in scala 2.9 and maybe not 2.8 either)

Use trunk:

```
scala> io.File("/etc/passwd").slurp
res0: String = 
##
# User Database
# 
... etc
```

Comment: "`slurp`"? Have we truly ditched obvious, intuitive name? The problem with `slurp` is that it might make sense after-the-fact, to someone with English as a first language, at least, but you would never think of it to begin with!

Comment: Just stumbled on this question/answer. `File` is no longer in 2.8.0, isn't it?

Comment: You can still sneak it in from scala.tools.nsc.io.File, though I assume that location may change in the future, so use at your own risk. ;-) Oh, and let me chime in to say how much I hate "slurp" as the name as well.

Comment: slurp sounds great. :) I wouldn't expect it, but I didn't expect output to the screen to be named 'print' either. `slurp` is fantastic! :) Was fantastic? I don't find it. ;(

Comment: in scala-2.10.0 the package name is scala.reflect.io.File

And a question about this "File". extempore, why is this file marked as "experimental"? Is it safe? Does it free a lock to the file system?

Comment: in Clojure it's also named slurp

Comment: slurp has a long history for this purpose originating, I think, from perl

Comment: Ok, it is good because not need `close`, is it?  And I can use it in any modern Scala, from 2.11 to 2.13 is it?

Answer (score 7):

I've been told that Source.fromFile is problematic. Personally, I have had problems opening large files with Source.fromFile and have had to resort to Java InputStreams.

Another interesting solution is using scalax. Here's an example of some well commented code that opens a log file using ManagedResource to open a file with scalax helpers: http://pastie.org/pastes/420714

Answer (score 7):

Using getLines() on scala.io.Source discards what characters were used for line terminators (\n, \r, \r\n, etc.)

The following should preserve it character-for-character, and doesn't do excessive string concatenation (performance problems):

```
def fileToString(file: File, encoding: String) = {
  val inStream = new FileInputStream(file)
  val outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream
  try {
    var reading = true
    while ( reading ) {
      inStream.read() match {
        case -1 => reading = false
        case c => outStream.write(c)
      }
    }
    outStream.flush()
  }
  finally {
    inStream.close()
  }
  new String(outStream.toByteArray(), encoding)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind a third-party dependency, you should consider using my [OS-Lib library](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib). This makes reading/writing files and working with the filesystem very convenient:

```
// Make sure working directory exists and is empty
val wd = os.pwd/"out"/"splash"
os.remove.all(wd)
os.makeDir.all(wd)

// Read/write files
os.write(wd/"file.txt", "hello")
os.read(wd/"file.txt") ==> "hello"

// Perform filesystem operations
os.copy(wd/"file.txt", wd/"copied.txt")
os.list(wd) ==> Seq(wd/"copied.txt", wd/"file.txt")
```

with one-line helpers for [reading bytes](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib#osreadbytes), [reading chunks](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib#osreadchunks), [reading lines](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib#osreadlines), and many other useful/common operations

Comment: Your libraries are excellent! Thank you for continuing to support them.

Answer (score 6):

Just like in Java, using CommonsIO library:

```
FileUtils.readFileToString(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Also, many answers here forget Charset. It's better to always provide it explicitly, or it will hit one day.

Answer (score 6):

One more: https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files#streams-and-codecs

Various ways to slurp a file without loading the contents into memory:

```
val bytes  : Iterator[Byte]            = file.bytes
val chars  : Iterator[Char]            = file.chars
val lines  : Iterator[String]          = file.lines
val source : scala.io.BufferedSource   = file.content
```

You can supply your own codec too for anything that does a read/write (it assumes scala.io.Codec.default if you don't provide one):

```
val content: String = file.contentAsString  // default codec
// custom codec:
import scala.io.Codec
file.contentAsString(Codec.ISO8859)
//or
import scala.io.Codec.string2codec
file.write("hello world")(codec = "US-ASCII")
```

Answer (score 4):

For emulating Ruby syntax (and convey the semantics) of opening and reading a file, consider this implicit class (Scala 2.10 and upper),

```
import java.io.File

def open(filename: String) = new File(filename)

implicit class RichFile(val file: File) extends AnyVal {
  def read = io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines.mkString("\n")
}
```

In this way,

```
open("file.txt").read
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to parse every single line and then concatenate them again...

```
Source.fromFile(path)(Codec.UTF8).mkString
```

I prefer to use this:

```
import scala.io.{BufferedSource, Codec, Source}
import scala.util.Try

def readFileUtf8(path: String): Try[String] = Try {
  val source: BufferedSource = Source.fromFile(path)(Codec.UTF8)
  val content = source.mkString
  source.close()
  content
}
```

Comment: You should close the stream - if error occurs in `val content = source.mkString`

Comment: +1 for `Codec`. I got test fail on `sbt test` because can't set it, while Intellij's test command pass all tests. And you can use `def using` from [this](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-open-read-text-files-in-scala-cookbook-examples)

Answer (score 3):

The obvious question being *"why do you want to read in the entire file?"* This is obviously not a scalable solution if your files get very large. The `scala.io.Source` gives you back an `Iterator[String]` from the `getLines` method, which is very useful and concise.

It's not much of a job to come up with an implicit conversion using the underlying java IO utilities to convert a `File`, a `Reader` or an `InputStream` to a `String`. I think that the lack of scalability means that they are correct not to add this to the standard API.

Comment: Seriously? How many files do you really read on a regular basis that have real problems fitting in memory?  The vast majority of files in the vast majority of programs I have ever dealt with are easily small enough to fit into memory.  Frankly, big data files are the exception, and you should realize that and program accordingly if you are going to be reading/writing them.

Comment: oxbow_lakes, I disagree.  There are many situations involving small files whose size will not grow in the future.

Comment: I agree that they are the exception - but I think that is why a read-entire-file-into-memory is not in either the JDK or the Scala SDK. It's a 3 line utility method for you to write yourself: get over it

Answer (score 3):

as a few people mentioned [scala.io.Source](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/branches/2.8.x/src/library/scala/io/Source.scala?view=markup) is best to be avoided due to connection leaks.

Probably scalax and pure java libs like commons-io are the best options until the new incubator project (ie scala-io) gets merged.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use Path from scala io to read and process files.

```
import scalax.file.Path
```

Now you can get file path using this:-

```
val filePath = Path("path_of_file_to_b_read", '/')
val lines = file.lines(includeTerminator = true)
```

You can also Include terminators but by default it is set to false..

Answer (score 3):

For faster overall reading / uploading a (large) file, consider increasing the size of `bufferSize` (`Source.DefaultBufSize` set to `2048`), for instance as follows,

```
val file = new java.io.File("myFilename")
io.Source.fromFile(file, bufferSize = Source.DefaultBufSize * 2)
```

Note [Source.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/io/Source.scala#L1). For further discussion see [Scala fast text file read and upload to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23007646/3189923).

Answer (score 1):

print every line, like use Java BufferedReader read ervery line, and print it:

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("test.txt" ).foreach{  print  }
```

equivalent:

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("test.txt" ).foreach( x => print(x))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import scala.io.source
object ReadLine{
def main(args:Array[String]){
if (args.length>0){
for (line <- Source.fromLine(args(0)).getLine())
println(line)
}
}
```

in arguments you can give file path and it will return all lines

Comment: What does this offer that the other answer don't?

Comment: Haven't seen other answers... just thought I can contribute here so posted... hopefully that will not harm anyone :)

Comment: You really should read them. Most are quite informative. Even the ones that are 8 years old have relevant information.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().mkString
```

however it should be noticed that getLines() removes all new line characters.
If you want save formatting you should use

```
Source.fromFile(fileName).iter.mkString
```

Comment: This answer doesn't bring any new help , there already loads of answers and comments saying the same thing. Unless you can add more context around this. Please do read : [How to give a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)