# Why are there no simple IO utils in the JDK for reading an entire file into a String?

Tags: java, file, io

In the comments to [my answer about reading an entire file into memory using `scala.io.Source`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284423/read-entire-file-in-scala/1285331#1285331), I asserted that the reason there is no read-whole-file-into-String method in Java is that it is not (of course) scalable with regards to how big the file is and how much heap you have.

However, I guess **everyone** has some method like:

```
String contents = IOUtil.readFile(f, "utf-8");
```

And the implementation of the method is just a few lines of code. **Why did they not just add this to the JDK in the first place?** Is it my (scalability) reason, or is there some other reason it was omitted?

Comment: "Why did they not just add this to the JDK in the first place?" Are you hoping one of the JDK authors will answer this question?  Or are you venting about something you don't like?

Comment: There's no end of "why isn't X in the JRE" questions, none of which are answerable.

Comment: But if it would have been harmful for reason that is not obvious, it would be interesting (and educational) to know why.

Comment: In programming, having a standard 10 tools that you can combine to do various jobs beats the hell out of having those 10 tools plus 1500 specific ones prebuilt out of the 10.  If you can do it in under 5 lines of code, just do it and leave libraries out of the picture (or write your own).  Java is not a scripting language, if it was then having everything in the standard libraries would make sense because you aren't really creating an entire app, you're creating a script where having to write your own subroutines is a larger portion of your code.

Comment: @S Lott: if you look at my question you will see that I at no point say that Sun were wrong not not to include it in the JDK. I was merely wanting to know what people thought the reasons for the omission were! I'm pretty annoyed this has been closed: it's a genuine question and it's programming related.

Comment: @skaffman: except possibly this one. All is required as an answer is an opinion on why it's not in there. But well done for the assumption that noone *else* could answer it!

Comment: `String wholeFile = new Scanner(pathToFile).useDeliminter("\\Z").next();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because files can be an arbitrary size, and it's just bad programming practice to do that sort of thing without a lot of checks and balances to make sure you're not crashing VM's left and right.

Comment: System.exit() crashes VMs left and right, but that's in the JRE. Proper documentation is the key.

Comment: Plus, methods like this exist in lots of other languages such as Python and C#.

Comment: I guess I'm happier with the JDK forcing programmers to (presumably) think the process through instead of "Here, call this and trash all of your memory!"

Answer (score 2):

I think your own answer is right. What if your file is like 1GB long?