# Reading a query from a sql file in resource folder in a spark/scala project code

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I have folder structure as below in IntelliJ
src --> main--> resources --> sql --> samplequery.sql
and I have scala object file  samplequeryexecute in folder src-- > main-->scala-->workflow

In samplequery.sql file , I have mentioned a simple query like
select * from tablename
In samplequeryexecute scala object file , just want to get the query from samplequery.sql and exexcute it. Assume all other necessary spark properties , I already have them.

Please suggest only the code for doing it.
I have not tried anything yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file from classpath without external dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121744/how-to-read-a-file-from-classpath-without-external-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to read a **classpath resource** line-by-line

```
import scala.io.Source

def readResourceAsStream(resourceName: String): Iterator[String] = {
  val resourceStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)
  if (resourceStream == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Resource not found: $resourceName")
  }
  Source.fromInputStream(resourceStream).getLines()
}
```

Usage:

```
val lines = readResourceAsStream("/sql/samplequery.sql")
lines.foreach(println)
```