# How can I write a text file in Scala in Windows?

Tags: scala

I can't use scalax because it is in a state between sbt 0.7.7 and sbt 0.11.2 and will not install on windows. (it is missing  org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.7.7;0.4.7-p10 even though I have downloaded that and changes scripts to match - newbie well out of his depth).

I can find no examples in the web without scalax.

All I want to do is write some lines of text to a file. However I don't want to have all lines in memory at once.

Can someone point me at an example?

Scala 2.9, Windows 7 - 64 bit.

Comment: I a previous answer, I showed how to write (or read) simple files without hassle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879427/scala-write-string-to-file-in-one-statement/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would probably be using `java.io.PrintWriter` like so:

```
scala> val pw = new java.io.PrintWriter("/tmp/foo.txt")
pw: java.io.PrintWriter = java.io.PrintWriter@1e1ff563

scala> pw.println("Hello")

scala> pw.close()
```

You might want to look up `PrintWriter` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

Comment: Glad I could help. Since I assume that you're fairly new to Scala, please allow me to hint you at [this nice compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) of questions and answers.

Comment: Great list - thanks. And your right - newbie on his first program in Scala, with no Java background :)