# How to save a Map result to a text file in Spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this:

```
val tokenFreq = reverseKey.countByKey
// tokenFreq: scala.collection.Map[String,Long] = Map(ABIGAIL -> 3,...
```

and I want to save the tokenFreq's result into a text file.

I tried to use saveAsTextFile, but it says:

> error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of scala.collection.Map[String,Long]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just convert the `Map` to an `RDD[(String, Long)]` then use the `RDD` api to save it.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TokenCounter").setMaster("local[4]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val tokenFreq = reverseKey.countByKey
sc.parallelize(tokenFreq.toSeq).saveAsTextFile("token_freq")
```

Of course, this will convert your data structure, however you can read it this `RDD` then collect it as a map to regain quick lookup.

```
val tokenFreqMap = sc.textFile("token_freq").collectAsMap
```

Answer (score 1):

As `countByKey` returns plain scala `Map`, you have to use scala's regular means to store it to the file.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577743/1349366) one way to do that:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter

new PrintWriter("filename") {
  tokenFreq.foreach {
    case (k, v) =>
      write(k + ":" + v)
      write("\n")
  }
  close()
}
```

Note, that this code will be executed on driver, after the result of `countByKey` is gathered from all workers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use saveAs* apis where your collection is distributed in your spark cluster. By using countByKey on RDD/DataFrame/DataSet, data will be collected among your data in cluster to your Spark driver. So you can't use saveAs* api on collected collections.