# How to save/read a Map using Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I recently wanted to know how to save a `HashMap` to file and later read it back. The user [Carrie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6100696/carrie) posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437400/how-to-save-a-map-result-to-a-text-file-in-spark-scala), but the accepted top answer can't be correct. Since I don't have enough reputation to comment that answer, I'm explaining one way to do this, in case someone has the same question.

---

### Question

I have a lookup map for a custom hash function where Integers are mapped to Sets of `(hash: Int, value: String)` tuples.

```
val lookupMap: Map[Int, Set[(Int, String)]] = ... // filling this map is a different story
```

I want to save this Map to a file and later read it bas as a map. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36440945/7018399) suggests to use `sc.textFile("...").collectAsMap`, but that doesn't work, because `textFile` returns `RDD[String]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Saving to file

Take the map and convert it to Seq. Then use `sc.parallelize` to form an RDD, which you save as an object file with `sc.saveAsObjectFile`.

```
val savePath = "lookup_map"    
val lookupMap: Map[Int, mutable.Set[(Int, String)]] = ... // fill your map
sc.parallelize(lookupMap.toSeq).saveAsObjectFile(savePath)
```

---

### Reading from file

To read your map, you have to know it's data type. In this case `Map[Int, mutable.Set[(Int, String)]]` was converted to a `Seq` which simply makes it `(Int, Set[(Int, String)])`. Then you can use `sc.objectFile[Type](path)` to read the file and collect it as a map with `collectAsMap`.

```
type LookupMapSeq = (Int, Set[(Int, String)])
val path = "lookup_map/part-[0-9]*"
val lookupMap = sc.objectFile[LookupMapSeq](path).collectAsMap()
```

As expected, the resulting data type is `Map[Int, Set[(Int, String)]]`.