# PySpark - Pass from a Collection to RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I've the following tranformation:

```
rdd1.map(lambda line: line[3]).countByValue()
```

How I can I store this in order to save the result as TextFile?

Because if I try to use:

```
rdd1.map(lambda line: line[3]).countByValue().saveAsTextFile("directory.txt")
```

However, the `saveAsTextFile` is not a part of collections. How can I do this?

Comment: what is `collections`?

Comment: @mad_ `countByValue` returns `Map[T, Long]` in Scala, `dict` in Python, so OP should use `reduceByKey`, not `countByValue`

Comment: why cant `collect()` or `values()` solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`countByValue`() converts result in a Map collection not a RDD.

`saveAsTextFile`() is defined to work on a RDD, not on a map/collection.

similar question with scala(countByKey) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437400/how-to-save-a-map-result-to-a-text-file-in-spark-scala)

you need to parallelize map and create a RDD and then save as text file

Comment: So I'm not able to export the result from the countByValue() to HDFS?

Comment: pls see the link example of how to do it. it was done for countByKey. in your case count by value.