# Scala Spark write string to file

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am using a Spark cluster and I want to write a string to a file and save it to the master node using Scala
I looked at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879427/scala-write-string-to-file-in-one-statement) and tried some of the suggestions, but I can't find the saved file

Comment: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to call collect on the RDD to bring the collection back to the driver. Then you can write it to the file system on the driver.

Although it would be recommended to write it in a parallelized fashion for performance.