# why can scala support this: new PrintWriter("filename") { write("file contents"); close }?

Tags: scala, syntax

I have a question regarding a trick

```
new PrintWriter("/tmp/some.file") { write("file contents"); close }
```

that I learned from this 
interesting post: [Scala: write string to file in one statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879427/scala-write-string-to-file-in-one-statement)

The technique  works great (for test code), however I am a little puzzled about what is going 
on syntactically in Scala.

PrintWriter is a java class... but it looks like a code block is 
being passed to the print writer instance, 
and implicitly method calls are being executed on that instance.
The PrintWriter java class definition has no apply() method that takes a 
function block.

So .. I'm puzzled as to what is going on visa vi Scala syntax

thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works because you are effectively creating an anonymous object that extends PrintWriter class. the code `write("file contents"); close` is simply part of the constructor of this anonymous object.

```
scala> val writer = new PrintWriter("/tmp/some.file") { write("file contents"); close }
writer: java.io.PrintWriter = $anon$1@6c07add6

scala> writer.getClass.getName
res4: String = $anon$1
```

Comment: s/anonymous object/anonymous class. the `new SomeClass { ... }` is also in Java, except in Java the code for constructor needs to be explicit. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: great answer !   embarrassed I didn't realize that ;^)

Comment: @ChrisBedford happens to the best of us :)