# Best way to represent a readline loop in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Coming from a C/C++ background, I'm not very familiar with the functional style of programming so all my code tends to be very imperative, as in most cases I just can't see a better way of doing it.

I'm just wondering if there is a way of making this block of **Scala** code more "*functional*"?

```
var line:String = "";
var lines:String = "";

do {
    line = reader.readLine();
    lines += line;
} while (line != null)
```

Comment: Psst, reading an entire file by doing line-by-line string appends is liable to be an `O(n^2)` operation!  (Formally it is; optimizations _might_ save you, but don't count on it.)  So this isn't a good way to write even imperative code unless your files are tiny.  (You'd use `StringBuilder` instead as the accumulator.)

Comment: **@Rex** Is it because of the abandoned String objects which are left behind when you do `+=` as Strings are immutable?

Comment: @Nick The main problem is that every time you do `s1 + s2` it has to create an entirely new string of size `s1.size + s2.size`, at proportional cost. Whereas when you append something to a `StringBuilder`, you don't have to pay again for the current contents of the `StringBuilder` (amortized cost, anyway).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about this?

```
val lines = Iterator.continually(reader.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null).mkString
```

Comment: Second answer is actually better. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What if the reader is a compressed file, or an internet URL, or something else?

Comment: This won't close the `Reader`, right? Same problem as Scala's `Source`.

Answer (score 14):

Well, in Scala you can actually say:

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").mkString
```

But this is just a library sugar. See [Read entire file in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284423) for other possiblities. What you are actually asking is how to apply functional paradigm to this problem. Here is a hint:

```
Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines().foreach {println}
```

Do you get the idea behind this? `foreach` line in the file execute `println` function. BTW don't worry, `getLines()` returns an iterator, not the whole file. Now something more serious:

```
lines filter {_.startsWith("ab")} map {_.toUpperCase} foreach {println}
```

See the idea? Take `lines` (it can be an array, list, set, iterator, whatever that can be filtered and which contains an items having `startsWith` method) and `filter` taking only the items starting with `"ab"`. Now take every item and `map` it by applying `toUpperCase` method. Finally `foreach` resulting item `print` it.

The last thought: you are not limited to a single type. For instance say you have a file containing integer number, one per line. If you want to read that file, parse the number and sum them up, simply say:

```
lines.map(_.toInt).sum
```

Answer (score 2):

To add how the same can be achieved using the formerly new `nio` files which I vote to use because it has several advantages:

```
val path: Path = Paths.get("foo.txt")
val lines = Source.fromInputStream(Files.newInputStream(path)).getLines()

// Now we can iterate the file or do anything we want,
// e.g. using functional operations such as map. Or simply concatenate.
val result = lines.mkString
```

Don't forget to close the stream afterwards.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `val lines = Source.fromFile("foo.txt").getLines(); val result = lines.mkString`? What are the advantages?

Comment: it uses an input stream which is an advantage, e.g. when testing. In actual code, when the input stream is part of the interface and not a string for a file name, the file can easily be replaced with some in memory data, e.g. buffered string or even an in memory file system.

Answer (score 1):

I find that `Stream` is a pretty nice approach: it create a re-traversible (if needed) sequence:

```
def loadLines(in: java.io.BufferedReader): Stream[String] = {
  val line = in.readLine
  if (line == null) Stream.Empty
  else Stream.cons(line, loadLines(in))
}
```

Each `Stream` element has a value (a `String`, `line`, in this case), and calls a function (`loadLines(in)`, in this example) which will yield the next element, lazily, on demand.  This makes for a good memory usage profile, especially with large data sets -- lines aren't read until they're needed, and aren't retained unless something is actually still holding onto them.  Yet you can also go back to a previous `Stream` element and traverse forward again, yielding the exact same result.