# Scala file slurp

Tags: scala

On this question

[Read entire file in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284423/read-entire-file-in-scala)

there is a comment to the first answer that reads

> but I'd hate for people not to know they can do "io.File("/etc/passwd").slurp" in trunk.

When I try to do that, scala tells me

```
error: object File is not a member of package io
```

I have scala 2.9.1-1. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1330808/571189) here...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

File isn't part of the stdlib anymore. Instead you should use `scala.io.Source`. To read an entire file you can do

```
val fileContents = io.Source.fromFile("my_file.txt").mkString
```

this should be avoided for large files though. In case of large files use `Source.getLines` instead and process the file line by line. `Source` also has a lot of other handy methods, so check them here http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source