# What is the fastest way to read an entire file into a String in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am currently using the following to do this.

```
val string = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath).mkString
```

However, I've noticed that it is quite slow. Is there any better (in terms of speed) method to read the whole file into a string?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284423/read-entire-file-in-scala) you might want to try something like `source.getLines mkString "\n"`

Comment: I did new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath))). Works like a breeze!

Comment: Was it appreciably faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following. This is much faster than my previous approach.

```
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

val string = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)))
```

Comment: You might want to specify the encoding too.