# Scala split on \n

Tags: scala

I have a text file with following contents-

```
"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\n\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t
Hotline: +49 40-300 51 701\n\t\n\t\n\t
Languages\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t
Travel plan \n\t\n\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t
Book\t
Packages from € 59\n
\tAccommodation and arrival\n
\tMusical packages\n
\tMaritime packages\n\t
Hamburg for Families\n\t
Experience Hamburg & Culture\n\n\n\n\n\t
Hotels from € 24\n\t
Book online now!\n\t
Theme hotels\n\t
Hotels by location\n\t
Special Offers\n\t
Hotels from A-Z\n\t
Other accommodation\n\n\n\n\n\t
Tickets from € 8\n\tBook online now!\n\t
Musicals Hamburg\n\tHamburg maritime\n\t
Sightseeing tours & city walks\n\tMuseums & Exhibitions\n\tHamburg for Families\n\n\n\n\n\t
Hamburg CARD\n\tBook online now!\n\tAll benefits at a glance\n\tFrequently asked questions\n\n\n\n\n\t
Group trips\n\tBooking request\n\tHamburg Guides and theme walks\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\n\t\tOffer\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\n\t\t
Hamburg CARD\n\t\tFree travel by bus, rail and ferry (HVV) and up to 50% discount on more than 150 tourist...\n\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t
from 10,50 EUR\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\n\t\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\tAttractions\tBest of Hamburg\n\t
Town Hall\n\tThe \"Michel\"\n\tSt. Pauli & Reeperbahn\n\t
Elbphilharmonie\n\tJungfernstieg\n\tMiniatur Wunderland\n\tTierpark Hagenbeck\n\t
All about the Alster\n\tBlankenese\n\n\n\n\n\tHamburg Maritime\n\t
Urbanshore Hamburg\n\tPort of Hamburg\n\tLandungsbrücken\n\tFish Market\n\tSpeicherstadt\n\tOn the Elbe\n\tHafenCity\n\tWillkomm-Höft\n\tÖvelgönne\n\n\n\n\n\tHistoric Hamburg\n\tThe Old Elbe Tunnel\n\t"
```

I want to split it on the \n. I tried

```
string.split("\n")
string.split('\n') 
string.split("""\n""") 
string.split("\\n")
```

Nothing of this seems to work. How do I get it done in scala?

Comment: all of those work for me - how are you reading the file?

Comment: var lines = Source.fromFile("/Users/rasika/Documents/example.txt").getLines.mkString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split by \n, then \t, flatten, then remove empty strings.

```
var lines = Source.fromFile("/Users/rasika/Documents/example.txt").getLines.mkString

val result = lines.split("\\\\n").flatMap(_.split("\\\\t")).filter(_.nonEmpty).toList
```

Result

> Hotline: +49 40-300 51 701
>   Languages
>   Travel plan
>   Book
>   Packages from € 59
>   Accommodation and arrival
>   Musical packages
>   Maritime packages
>   Hamburg for Families
>   Experience Hamburg & Culture
>   Hotels from € 24
>   Book online now!
>   Theme hotels
>   Hotels by location
>   Special Offers
>   Hotels from A-Z
>   Other accommodation
>   Tickets from € 8
>   Book online now!
>   Musicals Hamburg
>   Hamburg maritime
>   Sightseeing tours & city walks
>   Museums & Exhibitions
>   Hamburg for Families
>   Hamburg CARD
>   Book online now!
>   All benefits at a glance
>   Frequently asked questions
>   Group trips
>   Booking request
>   Hamburg Guides and theme walks
>   Offer
>   Hamburg CARD
>   Free travel by bus, rail and ferry (HVV) and up to 50% discount on more than 150 tourist...
>   from 10,50 EUR
>   Output exceeds cutoff limit.

Comment: Instead of splitting, could use linesIterator. The following would have the same end result: `lines.replace("\t", "\n").linesIterator.filterNot(_.trim.isEmpty).toList`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split on *literal* `\n` in your text (i.e. literal text, and not just a newline), then try this:

```
string.split("\\\\n")
```

In a regex context in Java/Scala, a literal backslash requires *four* backslashes.

Comment: If I do this, I get all the text as a single line.
I want every line of the text as an element in in a array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're splitting on newlines, and `io.Source.fromFile.getLines` separates on newlines, you'll need to read the whole file in one go instead, with

```
val string = io.Source.fromFile(filepath).mkString
```

as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1284446/5986907). Then your attempts should work e.g.

```
string.split('\n')
```