# Reading and Parsing Json file using Scala 2.12.8 in Intellij

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I am a newbie in Scala. I have a Json file with nested fields which must be read and parse. I read that and save the file in the Spark Dataframe; but I don't know how to access nested fields. This reading way is in following:

```
 val df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("src/main/scala/config.json")
 df.printSchema()
 df.show(false)
```

I searched and found this way to use and parse Json in Scala.This was using `os-lib` and the code is in the following:

```
 val jsonString = os.read(os.pwd/"src"/"main"/"scala"/"config.json")
 val data = ujson.read(jsonString)
 data.value
```

But I have error because of ***os***.

```
not found: value os
```

I add these dependencies in the ***build.sbt***:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "os-lib" % "0.9.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "3.0.0-M2"
```

However,the error still is there.I think it is because of Intellij Idea. What is wrong? What else I can do?

Would you please guide me how to read and parse Json File in Scala project inside Intellij Idea?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pure Scala your code seems working fine, the `not found: value os` could be a compile/import issue with the IDE you are using.

If you are using Intillj then you could try on the right side of the IDE click the `SBT` from the list of vertical tabs and reload all modules

---

You could use `from_json` in Spark

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*

val df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("src/main/scala/config.json")
val schema = schema_of_json(lit(df.select($"jsonCol").as[String].first))
df.withColumn("jsonData", from_json($"jsonData", schema))
df.select("jsonData.*").show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I said, I could read Json file and save it into Spark Dataframe. But, I want to access each field and save them in a list or variable.Converting from Spark Dtataframe takes extra times.

Comment: ohh I see, for the Scala issue I have tried your code and it seems working fine! I think it could be just a compile/index issue in the IDE you are using, if you are using Intillij then check `SBT` tab on the right side and rebuild the modules again. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I refresh ```SBT``` with error. Then wrote ***run*** in the ```shell sbt``` to see the error. It was because of conflict packages. I replaced ```libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "3.0.0-M2"``` with ```libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "0.9.5"``` and then refresh ```SBT``` again. Now it has no error.