# Scala File lines to Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm Currently opening my files and utilizing .getLines to retrieve each lines from the file with a word and its phonetic pronunciation separated by two white spaces, i'm confused as to how would i go about Mapping the word and its pronunciation in Scala as i'm fairly new to the language.
i've previously though to utilize split and separate the words and their sounds into different lines,but, i'm lost

Currently i Started with

```html
  def words(filename: String, word: String): Unit = {
    val file = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().drop(56)
    for(x <- file){
      
    }

 }
```

EX:

```
ARTI  AA1 R T IY2
AASE  AA1 S
ABAIR  AH0 B EH1 R
AB  AE1 B
```

Result:

```
Map("AARTI -> "AA1 R T IY2","AASE" -> "AA1 S", "ABAIR" -> " AH0 B EH1 R")
```

Answer (score 2):

- iterate each line
- split by 2 white spaces `"  "`
- create a tuple of (a -> b)
- convert `Array[Tuple[A, B]] => Map[A, B]`

example,

```
    val data =
      """
ARTI  AA1 R T IY2
AASE  AA1 S
ABAIR  AH0 B EH1 R
AB  AE1 B
      """.stripMargin

    val lines: Array[String] = data.split("\n").filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)
    // if you are reading from file
    // val lines = Source.fromFile("src/test/resources/my_filename.txt").getLines()

    val res: Array[Tuple2[String, String]] = lines.map { line =>
      line.split("  ") match { case Array(a, b) => a -> b }
    }

    println(res.toMap)
```

output:

```
Map(ARTI -> AA1 R T IY2, AASE -> AA1 S, ABAIR -> AH0 B EH1 R, AB -> AE1 B)
```

Running example - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/jBCnEhUPQJCMPKP9TXlgWA

[How to read entire file in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1284446/432903)

Comment: how would i go about it if i were reading through a file currently some of this text is in a txt file and i was currently looping to get the words

Comment: @Vanguard you are in right path. see the answer that just uncomment second `lines`  variable and provide path to your file

Answer (score 1):

If your lines are in `file` then this will create a `Map` from the first word to the rest of the string:

```
val res: Map[String, String] = file.map(_.span(_.isLetter))(collection.breakOut)
```

The values in the `Map` will contain leading space characters so you may want to call `trim` on them before using them.

1. The `map` call processes each line in turn.
2. The `span` method splits the line into a tuple where the first value is your word and the second is the rest of the line.
3. Using `collection.breakOut` tells `map` to put the results directly into a `Map` rather than going through an intermediate array or list.