# Printing a .txt file with a while loop

Tags: java, printing, while-loop, text-files

Im trying to print an entire .txt file.  I can only get the first line of the file to print.  I think I need a while loop to get the entire file to print?  From the examples Im finding on stack Im just getting confused.  This is my code.  How do I implement a while loop to print "file1"?

Thanks

```
fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("Folder/mytext.txt");
inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

file1 = inFS.next();

System.out.println( file1 );
```

Comment: http://www.java-examples.com/read-file-using-fileinputstream

Comment: This doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Folder\mytext.txt"));

 String line = null;

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
 }
```

Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/15696024/5224021