# Text printing in an infinite loop

Tags: java

The text is printing in an infinite loop. Any way to avoid these?

```
if (eLoad) {
    File file = new File("reservation.txt");

    /** reading a file */

    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        int content;
        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
            // convert to char and display it  
            System.out.print((char) content);
            /**print out the result contents of the file. */
        }
    }

    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ooutput shown

> Homeworkdue Sat Oct 10 00:00:00 PDT 2015 23:00 23
>   Homeworkdue Sat Oct 10 00:00:00 PDT 2015 23:00 23
>   Homeworkdue Sat Oct 10 00:00:00 PDT 2015 23:00 23

Comment: What is your text file content ?

Comment: HERE IS THE LINK TO SOLVE THOSE PROBELMS
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731365/reading-and-displaying-data-from-a-txt-file

Answer (score 0):

```
if (eLoad) {
    File file = new File("reservation.txt");

    /** reading a file */

    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        int content;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         // convert to char and display it  
            System.out.print(line);
            /**print out the result contents of the file. */
        }

        reader.close();
    }

    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think it is helpful? Because it isn't.

Comment: If file read is end then its return null then stop the execution that its break the loop.

Comment: So you still think the `int` variable `content` can be `null`?

Comment: Oh sorry I misread that line. Its working for if its string.

Comment: It won't, because `fis.read()` doesn't return a `String`. So there is other stuff to fix.

Comment: String line = null;        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    } In that way it can be work.

Comment: Yes, that is better. You may should update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add

```
System.out.print(content);
```

after

```
System.out.print((char) content);
```

I'm not very knowledgeable yet in programming but it may be because it is reading fis.read() as ASCII values, and it is either 000 or 003.

If so I would put

```
content = fis.read());
while (content != 3 && content != 0 || content == null) // if either not 3 and not 0 it doesn't run or if it isn't defined
{
    // do stuff
}
```

for the while condition

Quote:
"That means, the API try to read a line of file, get -1 and returns EOF."
(Looks like it doesn't return -1)

Looked at:
https://superuser.com/questions/789026/eof-ascii-hex-code-in-text-files

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to read in line by line from a file you could also try

```
 while ((line = fis.readLine()) != null) {
```

The rest of the code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (eLoad) {
    File file = new File("reservation.txt");

    /** reading a file */

    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        int content;
        while ((content = fis.read()) != 0) //JUST CHANGE THE -1 TO 0, THEN IT WORKS {
            // convert to char and display it  
            System.out.print((char) content);
        /**print out the result contents of the file. */
    }

    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```