# Get all text together from txt file and print to the console

Tags: java

I have a text file where text file Looks like `output.txt`

```
  | Component  | Tests Run   | Tests Failed                                   |
  |:-----------|:-----------:|:-----------------------------------------------|
  | Server     | 948         | :white_check_mark: 0                           |
  | Web Client | 123         | :warning: 2 [(see details)](http://linktologs) |
  | iOS Client | 78          | :warning: 3 [(see details)](http://linktologs) |
```

Here my work purpose I need to push all the code somewhere so that it will show like a table
I want to read all the text from the text file and print the text together.

**Currently its print line by line**

```
try {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Zsbappa\\Pictures\\test\\output.txt");
                int line;

                while ((line = reader.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char) line);
                }
                reader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Any suggestion will really appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading and displaying data from a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731365/reading-and-displaying-data-from-a-txt-file)

Comment: It's not duplicate sir.I want to get all the text together. They read line by line.Before adding flag you suppose to read details

Comment: what was the problem? this code works for me like charm

Comment: i want to get full text in one variable and print it..Its print line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, you want to **read** the file **all at once**, but only **print** it **line by line**.  I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but this should work:

```
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Zsbappa\\Pictures\\test\\output.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fis.read(data);
        fis.close();

        String str = new String(data, "UTF-8");

        String lines[] = str.split("\\r?\\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will be quite inefficient for large text files and will eat up your RAM, but this is the best solution I could think of for your specific problem.

Also remember to import `File` and `FileInputStream` since they are new standard library dependencies you are using.

Comment: Actually, I am integration a massager where if get all the output file and send it its will formatting like a table. This is my purpose.It will be not a big text file..Lets check your program

Comment: got an exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException in this line byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];

Comment: Does the file have anything in it?  Is it corrupted?  I don't see how getting the length of the file would return a negative number unless there is something wrong with your file.

Comment: Same text like output

Comment: I just edited my solution to have a proper `try` `catch` so that the error handling is done.  I copied your `output.txt` file to my computer and ran the program on it.  It printed fine.  Are you sure yours isn't corrupted (or that the path isn't messed up)?

Comment: sorry, I was missing the path. It's working perfectly for me now.Thanks, lots

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Java 8 or beyond, read them as a stream:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Zsbappa\\Pictures\\test\\output.txt")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: its work perfectly but not help me..Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("output.txt");
try {
   System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(inputStream));
} finally {
    inputStream.close();
}
```

The IOUtils class is part of the Apache Commons IO. It can be downloaded  [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

Comment: Its throwing error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)